# Bulma: No padding between level-item when expanded past 780px

Tags: html, css, sass, bulma

I have this html

```html
<body aurelia-app="main">


  <section class="section is-small">
    <nav-bar class="au-target" au-target-id="5">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item au-target" route-href="route: home" au-target-id="1" href="#/">
          <span class="icon is-medium">
            <i class="fas fa-lg fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" click.delegate="burgerClicked()" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="myNavBar" class="au-target navbar-burger burger" au-target-id="2">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="myNavBar" class="au-target navbar-menu" au-target-id="3">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <a route-href="route: games" class="au-target" au-target-id="4" href="#/games">My Games</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav-bar>
    <router-view name="main" class="container au-target" au-target-id="6">


  <available-games games.bind="games" class="au-target" au-target-id="11" bindable="games">

  <div class="columns">
    <ul class="column level">
      <li class="level-item">
        <game-button game.bind="game" is-available.call="isAvailable( $game )" class="au-target container" au-target-id="9" bindable="game,isAvailable">
  <button class="button is-fullwidth is-success au-target" click.delegate="addToMyGames()" disabled.bind="!available" au-target-id="7">
    Warhammer 40k
  </button>
</game-button>
      </li><li class="level-item">
        <game-button game.bind="game" is-available.call="isAvailable( $game )" class="au-target container" au-target-id="9" bindable="game,isAvailable">
  <button class="button is-fullwidth is-success au-target" click.delegate="addToMyGames()" disabled.bind="!available" au-target-id="7">
    Age of Sigmar
  </button>
</game-button>
      </li><!--anchor-->
    </ul>
  </div>
</available-games>
</router-view>
  </section>
</body>
```

it looks fine, until I expand it all the way, and then there is no space (height wise) between the full width buttons. I presume, I'm misunderstanding something about how I should be using bulma.

good
[image: good version]
bad
[image: bad version]

note: this is the extent of my scss

```
@import "~bulma";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";

$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a tip: fix formatting a bit to make it more consistent to readers - more clarity to the HTML hierarchy.

**Possible steps:**

1) It looks like you might need some padding between each `<button>` element inside some `<style>` tags or in your scss file that target the specific class attribute/element you need.

2) I'm confused about your `<game-button>` element. Is it a custom element you created? If it's not, see the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) for examples of how to create custom HMTL elements if you need it.

3) If `<game-button>` is not a custom element you created, see [Bulma's documentation for buttons](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/) because Bulma only requires a `<button>` element to work (and spacing wouldn't be an issue).

4) Check out this [GitHub post](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1872) regarding spacing between buttons. Although their implementation is different, you may still need to wrap your buttons in a `<div class="buttons"></div>` element. If there are issues after with inconsistent vertical alignment, I'd suggest using CSS `display: flex;`, `align-items: center`, and `justify-content: center` for centered alignment.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, forgot about the backpacks for the HTML elements and realized they didn't show. Corrected.

Comment: adding the undocumented `buttons` class is really all that's needed, as for html formatting, yes I didn't reformat it after I copied directly from chrome, rather than try to piece together aurelia's views and the various custom elements I made with aurelia (since none of that would impact the css, and in fact would probably confuse the situation), of course the custom elements do change the html structure, so... they could in fact cause css problems, thus I left them in the rendered output.

Comment: @xenoterracide Yay, there we go! Do you still have the same issue with spacing? Should I reword my answer a bit more?

Comment: spacing is oddly a little inconsistent, I don't really understand why level-item spacing disappears, but, it's got spacing now, so that'll do.

Comment: No problem! Glad you found the issue. Yes, I do agree; perhaps it was a design decision that level wouldn't have item spacing but I suppose it was due to @jgthms's reasoning that the level had a specific use-case, hmmm.